# Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am try to insert data to DB

```
 let sql =`INSERT INTO \`${tableName}\`(`
         const keysString = keys.join(',')
         const valuesString =values.join(',')
         sql =`${sql}${keysString}VALUES(${valuesString})`
```

but have err

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES('10c153e878a291a4fc8eb6a2ccda6e01','http://localhost:8089/admin-upload-eb' at line 1
```

print sql

```
INSERT INTO `book`(`filename`,`cover`,`title`,`author`,`publisher`,`bookId`,`updateType`,`language`,`rootFile`,`originalName`,`filePath`,`unzipPath`,`coverPath`,`createUser`,`createDt`,`updateDt`,`category`,`categoryText`VALUES('10c153e878a291a4fc8eb6a2ccda6e01','http://localhost:8089/admin-upload-ebook/img/10c153e878a291a4fc8eb6a2ccda6e01.jpeg','The Economy as a Complex Spatial System','Pasquale Commendatore, Ingrid Kubin, Spiros Bougheas, Alan Kirman, Michael Kopel and Gian Italo Bischi','Springer International Publishing, Cham','10c153e878a291a4fc8eb6a2ccda6e01','1','en','OEBPS/content.opf','2018_Book_TheEconomyAsAComplexSpatialSys.epub','/book/10c153e878a291a4fc8eb6a2ccda6e01.epub','/unzip/10c153e878a291a4fc8eb6a2ccda6e01','/img/10c153e878a291a4fc8eb6a2ccda6e01.jpeg','admin','1586248853120','1586248853120','99','obj')
```

Answer (score 0):

i have lose a ')'  in last line

```
 let sql =`INSERT INTO \`${tableName}\`(`
             const keysString = keys.join(',')
             const valuesString =values.join(',')
             sql =`${sql}${keysString})VALUES(${valuesString})`
```